# Android Listview Button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, android-listview

I have a listview that has two textviews and a button. If the button is clicked, it changes to a "stop" button image and if another row's button is clicked, the previous button goes back to "play" button image and the the new row's button changes to the "stop" button image. All these are working for the first 2-3 rows. After scrolling down, it stops to work and gives me a `NullPointerException`. I'm guessing it has to do with listview's viewgroup recycling. If anyone can help me out here, it'll be great.

Here is the code for my adapter's onclicklistener:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final MyViewHolder holder;
        if (ConvertView == null){
            ConvertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            holder = new MyViewHolder();        
            holder.plays = (ImageButton) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.plays);
            holder.plays.setFocusable(false);
            holder.plays.setOnClickListener(this);
            parents = parent;
            }else{
                holder = (MyViewHolder)ConvertView.getTag();
            }


            play = playdata.get(pos);
            holder.posturl= play.getposturl();






            holder.plays.setTag(pos);    
            ConvertView.setTag(holder);



            if(mHighlightedPositions[pos]) {
                holder.plays.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_stop);
            }else {
                holder.plays.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
            }





        play = playdata.get(pos);
        holder.play = play;

        return ConvertView;



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = (Integer)view.getTag();
            Log.d("clicked", "Button row pos click: " + position);


            // Toggle background resource
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton)layout.getChildAt(3);

            if(initialposition!=-1)
            {if(mHighlightedPositions[position]) {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                mHighlightedPositions[position] = false;
            }else {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_stop);
                mHighlightedPositions[position] = true;
                mHighlightedPositions[initialposition]=false;
                LinearLayout parentlayout = (LinearLayout) parents.getChildAt(initialposition);
                ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) parentlayout.getChildAt(3);
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);

            }
            }else {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_stop);
                mHighlightedPositions[position] = true;
            }
            initialposition = position;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm getting nullpointerexception in this bit:

```
LinearLayout parentlayout = (LinearLayout) parents.getChildAt(initialposition);
                    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) parentlayout.getChildAt(3);
                    btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
```

Also, Logged the nullpointerexception, and it's when scrolling that parentlayout becomes null.

Comment: what is mHihglightedPositions and where is it set?

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the error, in case there is no third child of the layout or there is no layout. Try to check, whether `layout` or `button` actually have the content you want:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();
if(layout != null) { 
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton)layout.getChildAt(3);
} else {
    Log.d("Error", "No Parent Layout");
}
if(button != null) {
    //do your stuff
} else {
    Log.d("Error", "No Third Child");
}
```